# Ver meses del calendario Javascript

Tags: javascript, tabla-dinámica

Estoy intentando hacer un calendario como el de esta web: https://devcode.la/tutoriales/calendario-con-javascript/ lo que en lugar de que los meses me aparezcan en vertical, me gustaría que aparecieran cuatro meses por cada línea, en plan Enero-Febrero-Marzo-Abril y ya abajo 4 más y así...

El paso por el que voy es el siguiente:

```js
var mes_text = ["Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre"];

function estructurar() {
 for (m = 0; m <= 11; m++) {
  //Mes
  let mes = document.createElement("DIV");
  mes.className = "mes";
  document.body.appendChild(mes);
  //Tabla
  let tabla_mes = document.createElement("TABLE");
  tabla_mes.className = "tabla_mes";
  mes.appendChild(tabla_mes);
  //Título
  let titulo = document.createElement("CAPTION");
  titulo.className = "titulo";
  titulo.innerText = mes_text[m];
  tabla_mes.appendChild(titulo);
}
}
```

Supongo que tendrá que ver con el `AppendChild` pero no lo tengo muy claro, estoy practicando para aprender. Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda.

Comment: Puedes colocar una imagen de ejemplo para ver como te esta quedando y a lo que quieres llegar? así te podemos ayudar de mejor forma.

Comment: Solo estoy intentando hacer el calendario como el de la web que he puesto pero en lugar de que me aparezcan los meses uno por uno, cada uno en una fila, que me aparezcan 4 por fila

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se porque estas creando una tabla por mes.  Yo haria una sola tabla que contenga todos los meses.  Algo asi:

```js
var mes_text = ["Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre"];

function estructurar() {
  let mes = document.createElement("DIV");
  mes.className = "mes";
  document.body.appendChild(mes);
  let tabla_mes = document.createElement("TABLE");
  tabla_mes.className = "tabla_mes";
  mes.appendChild(tabla_mes);
  let tr = "";
  for (m = 0; m <= 11; m++) {    
    if (m % 4 == 0) {
      tr = tabla_mes.insertRow(m / 4);
    }
    var cell = document.createElement("td");    
    var cellText = document.createTextNode(mes_text[m]);  
    
    cell.appendChild(cellText);
    tr.appendChild(cell);
    
  }
}
estructurar();
```

Comment: Según el tutorial, creo que hace una tabla para los días de cada mes.

Comment: Oh, en ese caso puedes tener una tabla que encierre a las tablas por mes.

Comment: Sí, así me funciona pero siguiendo el tutorial en los pasos siguientes se me queda todo mal. Supongo que es lo que has dicho, pero no se como se haría la tabla que encerrara todas las tablas por mes

Comment: ya edite la respuesta

Comment: @alanfcm la verdad es que me he quedado atascado en este paso...se podría crear la tabla con html y rellenarla con JavaScript?